ldapsearch command suddenly stopped working on my Mac
I used to be able to run ldapsearch commands from my mac. But it suddenly stopped working since yesterday
Below is how my config file looks and it has remained like this for sometime now.
$ cat /etc/openldap/ldap.conf |grep -v ^# |awk NF
BASE    dc=domain,dc=com
URI ldap://ldaphost.domain.com
TLS_REQCERT never

I can see the domain name getting added twice like ldap/ldaphost.domain.com@domain.COM during the search.Any ideas on where it might be getting it from, and is it cause of the failures?
$ ldapsearch samaccountname=userid
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (Server (ldap/ldaphost.domain.com@domain.COM) unknown while looking up 'ldap/ldaphost.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM' (cached result, timeout in 242 sec))

